# Question marks appear in Distance (similarity measure object)

Tags: rapidminer

I am trying to use KLDivergence for measuring similarity between text data. But, although other similarity measures work fine, KLDivergence returns question marks in the result. What can cause this problem?[image]

Answer (score 0):

If any of the attributes has a value of zero, the KLdivergence will produce the missing result (the ?). This is probably because of a division by zero.

Comment: You could use the R extension and take advantage of packages that calculate the KL distance. One that I found is called FNN and has a function  KL.dist. I tried it with data containing zeroes and it gave a result.